# Create the import control file to import the XML

Tags: xml, informatica

I am new in informatica, I just want to import the XML. To do this stuff I have below command

```
pmrep objectimport -i ${XML_DIR}/${xml_file} -c ${CFN_DIR}/${cfn_file} -l ${PMLogDir}/${log_import_file}
```

But I haven't any idea to create the CFN file (import control file).

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Have you checked [PMREP ObjectImport Control File Templates](https://community.informatica.com/solutions/pmrep_object_import_control_files)?

Comment: Hi Marek..This is posted by me and didn't get any response on that. that's why I have posted the same on stackoverflow

Comment: In informatica community, I have posted the same question. and I haven't client I just need to import by using commands in linux env

Comment: You need to create the .cnf file manually. The link I provided contains a few sample files and there is a section *Using the Object Import Control File* in the documentation. What's your problem specifically? Have you created a file and the import fails?